# Вызвать отложенный метод из метода сервиса. Паттерн наблюдатель

Tags: java, spring, rest

Есть post метод `putMessage(Some object)` который принимает на вход данные, обрабатывает их и возвращает пользователю сообщение *"загрузка файла прошла успешно"*.

После того как метод обработал данные и перед тем как вернуть пользователю *"загрузка файла прошла успешно"*, мне нужно еще запустить отдельный метод `void2()` который выполняет работу около 2-3 часов.

Как вызвать внутри `putMessage(Some object)` этот метод чтобы его выполнение началось отдельно и клиент не ждал сообщение 2-3 часа. Я слышал что это можно реализовать через Наблюдателя. есть для этого инструмент в `Spring`?

т.е.

```
String putMessage(Some object){
    // 1. обработка данных object
    // 2. вызов void2() * - вынести в отдельный поток
    // 3. return "загрузка файла прошла успешно";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нужно включить инфраструктуру для запуска асинхронных методов.

В java конфигyрации нужно добавить аннотацию `@EnableAsync`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig { ... }
```

или в xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd"
>

    <task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor"/>
    <task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
     
    ...
</beans>
```

Потом, помечаете метод, который хотите чтобы выполнялся в отдельном потоке, аннотацией `@Async`:

```
@Async
public void void2() {
    // этот метод выполнится в отдельном потоке
}
```

Это самая простая конфигурация. Дополнительно можно еще:

1. конфигурировать executor, например, сколько потоков для асинхронных задач будет доступно
2. добавлять обработчик ошибок, для асинхронных методов
3. запускать метод из основного (как в этом случае `putMessage`), и ждать когда закончится выполнение и вернуть результат работы

Ну и [тут](https://spring-projects.ru/guides/async-method/) есть полностью рабочий пошаговый пример с объяснением по-русски.